# Como puedo exportar por rango de fecha en Android Java, mi app exporta el total pero cuando pongo un rango de fecha me sigue exportando igual todo

Tags: java, android, excel, date

Como se puede ver en la imagen , hay 2 registros , el cual si doy en el boton exportar , me genera el excel de los 2 registros, pero si solo quiero por un rango de fecha no me da ese resultado y me sigue exportando el total de la lista

**Ayuda porfavor**

[image: Imagen de mi App , genera el xlsx pero no por filtro de fechas]

```
private void createXlsx(List<Incidencia> incidencias) {

    try {
        String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File root2 = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "FileExcel");
        if (!root2.exists())
            root2.mkdirs();

        File path = new File(root2, "/" + strDate + ".xlsx");

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);

        XSSFCellStyle headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.BLUE_GREY.getIndex());
        headerStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        headerStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        headerStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        headerStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        headerStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);

        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
        font.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
        font.setBold(true);
        headerStyle.setFont(font);

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FORMATO FA-16");
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
```

Comment: En tu código no hay ningún lugar donde insertes el rango de fecha, o si?